# I want editables but without forms or Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-docs

I want my users to be able to edit text on their page (not all) without showing them a form. At the same time, I do not want it to be to an editable, because there are too many of them and is not usable. The best would be something like google docs, where the user can read his text and seamlessly update it, without any hassle.

Does anyone know of a jquery plugin that can do this? If you think I should just use one of the rich text editors at each location, please tell me so.

On the same note, I have seen a couple of sites which allow users to edit content in divs without changing the element. Can anyone tell me how its done?

Comment: Chances are that these site you mention, actually **do** replace the elements - although you could run a keypress handler on the element - so when a user types, it can append to the contents?

Comment: nope. especially google docs, doesn't change the element. Each line is in its own div.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sites I've seen that let you edit the contents of a div do so by adding a click event to the div which removes the contents of the div and adds an editable and a button to the div.

When the user clicks the new button, the editable and button are hidden and whatever is in the editable is used as the new content of the div.  Often, there is an AJAX call to take some action on the back-end as well.

Also, the button may be replaced with an event handler on the editable which takes action on Enter or Esc.

Note that `content-editable` is HTML5, so it won't work in all browsers, yet.

**EDIT**

It turns out `content-editable` is pretty well supported (http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable), but still may not be what you want.

Comment: Yeah, content-editable support actually dates back to IE6, if I'm not mistaken, so most modern browsers will reliably support it.

Comment: @Moses: IE 5.5 actually :) IE had it way before (around 5 years) everyone else though. Firefox was the last major browser to add support `contenteditable`, which they did in version 3.0 in June 2008.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is pretty  much what I want.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make a DOM element editable, you can attach the attribute/value pair `content-editable="true"` to the tag. For example,

```
<!-- all text within this <div> can be edited by the user -->
<div content-editable="true">
    Lorem ipsum doler sit amet
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) which has a live [demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html).

Another option I could suggest if you don't like the idea of a form.  Maybe you could just style the input, textarea's so they don' have the "form" look to them.

Comment: I have looked at it. I do not want to use it. There are too many editables and becomes unusable because its confusing when there are so many there. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 http://html5demos.com/contenteditable
Content editable is an html 5 which means not alot of browsers support it.

2 This option is a bit more visual effects than anything else.

```
<textarea style="border: none;">Blabla</textarea>



 $('textarea').keyup(function (){           
         // here u can do ur cool stuff to autosave when a user rests for 2 secondes or more 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a new answer, I found this plugin that does everything I wanted. I have to write even less code :) http://valums.com/edit-in-place/